# Multiple Application Uninstall by checkboxes

Tags: android

I want to uninstall multiple applications by checking checkbox.. problem is when i check multiple apps to uninstall it alerts "Are you sure you want to uninstall this App" every time. I want only one alert and the code uninstalls all checked Applications.

```
private void displayListView() {

    ArrayList<App> appList = new ArrayList<App>();
    App app = null;
    List<PackageInfo> list = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    String name = "";
    String path = "";
    String capName = "";
    for (PackageInfo p : list) {
        if ((p.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {

        } else {
            name = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
                    .toString();
            capName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            path = p.applicationInfo.packageName;

            if ((!name.equals("com.android.gesture.builder"))
                    && (!capName.equals(path))) {
                app = new App(path, name, false);
                app.setVersionCode(p.versionCode);
                app.setVersionName(p.versionName);
                app.setIcon(p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));
                appList.add(app);

            }
        }

    }

    // create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_app_list,
            appList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // app app = (app)
            // parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            App ap = (App) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ap.getName(),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent itn = new Intent(AppManagement.this, AppInfo.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("name", ap.getName());
            extras.putString("path", ap.getpath());
            extras.putString("vName", ap.getVersionName());
            extras.putString("vCode", ap.getVersionCode() + "");
            itn.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(itn);
        }
    });

}

public void checkButtonClick() {

    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();

            ArrayList<App> appList = dataAdapter.appList;
            App app = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) {
                app = appList.get(i);
                if (app.isSelected()) {
                    urr = Uri.fromParts("package", app.getpath(), null);
                    Log.d("", urr.toString());
                    responseText.append("\n" + app.getName() + " \t "
                            + app.getpath());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, urr);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                }

            }

            if (responseText.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No App selected ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseText,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

public void onActivityResult(int rCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (rCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            displayListView();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently available to third party applications. You will have to take permission from user for each install/uninstall.

Comment: ok i got it means that its the system privileges , one can not change this setting??? but someone told me that it is possible to uninstall apps on a single alert ..

Comment: Single alert for a single app.